# PyODBC and MariaDB: Text column truncates strings longer than 127 characters

Tags: python, mariadb, odbc, pyodbc

I am using PyODBC version 4.0.39 and MariaDB version 11. In my database, I have a text column where I need to store strings. However, I've noticed that when I try to insert a string with a length greater than 127 characters, it gets truncated and turns into gibberish.

I have also noticed that if I avoid using data binding and directly pass the parameter in the SQL query, there is no truncation issue. However, I am reluctant to adopt this approach because of the vulnerability to SQL injection attacks.

Here is a sample input string:
"{Some data}"

What I see in the database after inserting the string is:
'[some data], ''ServiceI✀㨀 ㈀紀'

The code I am executing to perform the insertion is as follows:

```
def runQueryAndGetAffectedRowsSynchronous(self, transaction: List[Tuple[str, Tuple]]):
    cncx = self.__DatabaseConnection.cursor()
    affectedRowCount = []
    try:
        for t in transaction:
            count = cncx.execute(t[0], t[1]).rowcount
            affectedRowCount.append(count)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        cncx.rollback()
    else:
        cncx.commit()
    finally:
        cncx.close()
    return affectedRowCount
```

My connection string:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={MariaDB ODBC 3.1 Driver};SERVER='+self.__server+';DATABASE='+self.__database+';ENCRYPT=no;UID='+self.__username+';PWD='+ self.__password+";Trusted_connection=no"+";Port="+str(self.__port))
```

I would like to know why this truncation is happening and how I can resolve it to store the complete string in the text column. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the table definition from the database please (`SHOW CREATE TABLE ...`)

Answer (score 1):

pyodbc can handle the encoding for you, as documented tn the wiki

https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Unicode#mysql

```py
cnxn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='utf-8')
cnxn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, encoding='utf-8')
cnxn.setencoding(encoding='utf-8')
```

That way you don't have to remember to encode every string yourself.

Answer (score -2):

I have resolved the problem of string truncation in PyODBC and MariaDB. The solution is to encode the string using the encode() method with the utf-8 encoding before executing the SQL query. This ensures that the complete string is stored in the database without any truncation.
Example:
v = v.encode(encoding="utf-8")